# Do I need to fix my weirdo partitions? I don't have root or /home

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, root

I'm running a dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10. I wanted to resize my linux-swap partition. I did that: unmounted and deleted original, extended Ubuntu partition through new unallocated space while leaving enough for the new linux-swap, then created a new swap partition from this remainder.

But in the process of looking at tutorials it became abundantly clear that some nonsense happened while I was setting my dual boot up. This was it when I opened gparted (though the swap used to be larger).

[Laugh at my weirdo partitions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG1lV.png)

I don't appear to have a formal home partition nor a root partition. Everything is labeled sda.

- **sda1:** I know I needed the EFI partition because I was warned online to not get rid of it on account of running a UEFI, non-legacy-compatible machine. [Here's a question I asked about that a bit ago.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954020/can-boot-repair-fix-my-dual-boot-with-the-legacy-uefi-conversion-if-my-window)
- **sda2:** I assume this is some Microsoft stuff.
- **sda3:** This is the Windows OS and data.
- **sda4:** I don't know!
- **Unallocated:** When I tried to merge this into sda5 gparted told me I was going to mess up my boot, so I left it.
- **sda5:** All of Ubuntu and data. I extended this guy with the extra linux-swap stuff.
- **sda6:** linux-swap, i.e. what I made smaller. I guess when I installed Ubuntu I put this after? I read best-practice is to locate it before if you're running an HDD, but I'm running an SSD. It's actually labeled a primary partition.
- **sda7:** Lenovo has its own recovery partition. I assume I shouldn't mess with this, given when I tentatively tried to in the past Lenovo essentially told me I couldn't update any Lenovo drivers, components, and my computer might be read as stolen.

My computer came with Windows 7, I upgraded to Windows 10, and a while after that I installed Ubuntu. It has been so long I could not tell you what I did besides using the Official Windows Update Tool for the first and the Live CD (or USB) for the second. Everything's been running fine, no indication that anything was the matter.

What is happening here? Do I need to fix it, and how would I do so? Should I somehow move my Ubuntu stuff to root and /home partitions? Is my linux-swap even being utilized--it was its own primary partition before I resized it, and it wouldn't let me create it as anything but as a primary partition after I resized it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see for linux you have a root `/` partition and a swap partition. This is enough. `/home` is quite fine within your root partition. (There are advantages in having them separately but their are not mandatory.) For example my home folder is within the root partition just like yours.

So as far as linux is concerned you are fine.

The 1MiB unallocated space you can ignore. I don't know why somethimes there's space left between partitions but it's so small it's not worth the trouble.

Can't tell what sda4 is but it looks small enough that you can ignore it. You could try asking at superuser site what it is (assuming it comes from the windows side of things).

sda7 I think is so you can bring your laptop to factory default settings. When I tried it on my old asus laptop though it couldn't configure/replace grub so the system didn't boot unless I pointed it to a live USB from the bios. So beware.

sda2 may be something similar - not really sure.

Overall I 'd say your system is ok.

Comment: Oh jeez, the root indication is under "mount point". Well, now I feel dumb. Thank you!

Comment: The unallocated space between partitions is for better alignment. Please leave it as is.